# Can't display german umlauts even if UTF-8 is set wherever possible

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Let me explain situation closer.

1. Im working on some old company server with PHP 4. There is Windows 2000NT installed and a databaze that I can open with Microsoft Access 2000.
2. There is no any option to set character encoding (unlike in phpMyAdmin), but I can read that characters in MS Access properly.
3. Im extracting data from that database in my .php files and displaying it on my website, but characters like: "ü, ä, ß" are displayed wrongly, like this: �
4. All php/html files are saved by some old version of Notepad++ as UTF-8 encoding and containing:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I read some theory about character encoding, history of character encoding and almighty UTF-8 that will solve all your problems, which is simply not true. What could be wrong?

Comment: you can try to convert characters with http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, identify what byte values your broken characters have exactly. Without knowing you cannot identify the encoding like to be used.

```
echo urlencode($string_with_umlauts);
```

This will print all non-ascii characters as percent-encoded hex values. Note that this function is meant for some other purpose, but it'll help in this case also.

Then lookup the bytes in encoding tables like Wikipedia and be sure what you have there.

The last step: Add a transformation layer to your database access logic that converts from the encoding you saw to UTF-8 with iconv functions.

Comment: Well, with urlencode()  I get %DF for ß, %E4 for ä and %F6 for ö. This match with Windows-1252 encoding. I changed html meta tag to <meta charset="Windows-1252">  but still the same result �.

Comment: You are supposed to change the encoding of the strings, because that is an easy one step process, instead of changing the declaration of the encoding, because this happens in at least TWO places - the HTTP header takes priority over the HTML information, and you didn't change the HTTP header, did you? Additionally, using UTF-8 makes everything so much easier, and allows to also receive every possible character back from the user. You shouldn't want to stick with something else. :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I don't fully understand, how could I change encoding of what strings?

Comment: Unfortunately iconv() is not supported on that server.

Comment: There's more than one function dealing with changing the encoding, for example `utf8_encode()` assumes you have ISO-8859-1 strings - which is roughly correct if you assume Windows-1252, with some minor details wrong, i.e. Windows-1252 allows to encode more characters which are undefined in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found solution:

```
function decode($string){

$string = urlencode($string);
$string = str_replace('%DF','ß',$string);
$string = str_replace('%E4','ä',$string);
$string = str_replace('%F6','ö',$string);
$string = str_replace('%2B','+',$string);
$string = str_replace('%FC','ü',$string);
$string = str_replace('%26','&',$string);
$string = str_replace('%2F','/',$string);
$string = str_replace('%0A','',$string);
$string = str_replace('%0D','',$string);
$string = str_replace('%40','@',$string);
$string = str_replace('%2C',',',$string);
$string = str_replace('%E1','á',$string);
$string = str_replace('%D3','ó',$string);
$string = str_replace('+',' ',$string);

return $string;
```

}

But isn't there any better solution?

Comment: Yes. Use the `iconv()` function.