# PHP / MS Access encoding issue with German characters

Tags: php, encoding, ms-access-2000

Can't figure out the reason for German characters do not display properly in MS Access 2000, when they are INSERTED from PHP (because if I insert german character directly from ms access interface - it is all good).

Using PDO, PHP 5.6.

Tried to convert from UTF-8 to different encodings: Windows-1250, 1251,1252,1256, and some others..

I'm stuck with this. If someone knows the solution, I will really appreciate that!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't display german umlauts even if UTF-8 is set wherever possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520144/cant-display-german-umlauts-even-if-utf-8-is-set-wherever-possible)

Comment: There is an opposite situation - data from db can't be displayed normally, but here I need ms access to display them as it should.